# Why does microk8s keep complaining that the memory cgroup is not enabled?

Tags: 22.04, kubernetes

I have several raspberry pie's with ubuntu 22.04 installed on them. On them I have installed microk8s (1.25). I have also enabled the memory cgroup as per the instructions here: https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives#heading--arm.

```
ubuntu@pi43:$ cat /proc/cmdline
coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=0 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=0 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=E4:5F:01:0B:14:8A vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc quiet splash cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1
```

So it would appear that the memory cgroup is enabled.

However when I run a microk8s inspect I get the warning that this is not the case:

```
ubuntu@pi43:$ sudo microk8s inspect
Inspecting system
(...)
WARNING:  The memory cgroup is not enabled.
The cluster may not be functioning properly. Please ensure cgroups are enabled
```

Why would that be?